# Python complex numbers from C++ strange output

Tags: python, c++, translate

I'm working on translating some code from C++ to Python and some values in python output are wrong. The expected output is pairs of numbers stored in the array. In the python, I get a lot of 1-0j pairs first and then good ones. In C++ the greatest value is around 1.3 and in Python over 9. How do I have to modify my python code to get the output from C++.

main func C++, I know that S do nothing but I'll use it later:

```
int X = 1000;
int N = X;

complex<double> S;

for (int n=0; n<X; n++)
{
    S = complex<double>(0,0);
    for (int x=0; x<X; x++)
    {
        double r = cos(((2*M_PI)/X)*n*x);
        double i = sin(((2*M_PI)/X)*n*x);
        complex<double> t (r, -i);
        cout << t << endl;
    }
}
```

Python:

```
import numpy as np
from math import pi
import sys
 
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

X = 1000
N = X
S = np.zeros(0, dtype = complex)
T = np.zeros(0, dtype = complex)

n = 0
x = 0
for n in range(0, 1000, 1):
     # S = np.append(S, np.complex(0 ,0)
  
    for x in range(0, 1000, 1):
        r = np.cos(((2*pi)/X)*n*x)
        i  = np.sin(((2*pi)/X)*n*x)
        T = np.append(T, np.complex(r, -i))
        print(T)
        print('\n')
```

Comment: Can you post a section of the output from each piece of code? When running the python code myself I see values like `9.51056516e-01j` which isn't 9.5... but actually 0.95...

Comment: I concur with @Kevin, I believe the formatting messed you up.  This code should never output a value that is greater than 1.0: abs(T) <= 1.

Comment: Eh, yes, my fault. with '.' . But you don't see "1.00000000e + 00-0.j"? When I started my Python program it showed me a lot in the beginning?

Comment: Because when `n` is 0 (which is true for the first 1000 values) you're calculating `cos(0)` and `sin(0)` which will give you a complex number of `1 + 0i`

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear why you think your Python code is equivalent to your C++ code. `T = np.append(T, np.complex(r, -i))` is not equivalent to `complex<double> t (r, -i);`. The actual equivalent Python code to your C++, which produces the same output, is:

```
from numpy import cos, sin, pi # could also import from math instead of numpy, might affect speed though
X = 1000

for n in range(X):
    for x in range(X):
        r = cos(((2*pi)/X)*n*x)
        i = sin(((2*pi)/X)*n*x)
        t = complex(r, -i)
        print(t)
```

The way I tested this was by setting `X` to `5` in both sets of code and comparing the output. They were the same (with Python just showing more digits of precision).

Answer (score 1):

This is my conversion of the C++ code.  I maintained the array creation, but pre-allocated them rather than using np.append (unnecessarily slow when you already have the array length defined).  Also added formatting to the "print" statement.  Note that printing a million values takes a terribly long time, so I suggest commenting out the print line, or reducing the value of X to 50 or less.

```
import numpy as np
import sys

np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

X = 1000
N = X

S = np.zeros((N*X,), dtype=complex)
T = np.zeros((N*X,), dtype=complex)

k = 0

for n in range(0, N):
    # Not sure what you were trying to do with "S"
    for x in range(0, X):
        r = np.cos((2*np.pi/X)*n*x)
        i = np.sin((2*np.pi/X)*n*x)
        T[k] = np.complex(r, -i)
        print('{val:14.3f}'.format(val=T[k]))
        k += 1
```